# NLP extract category from text using java

Tags: java, text, nlp, named-entity-extraction

How to classify the words extracted from a text (using NLP/NLTK or Textblob) in entities and categories (from lists or taxonomy) ?

I will have keyword database and I would like to extract line by line from a text the matching keyword.

For example below a text file

> Date, Description,    Money in (€),   Money out (€)
>   1) 3-Mar-16,    CNC CNCWORD1 CNCWORD2 P 01/03 3,    ,   2.95
>   2) 3-Mar-16 POS POSWORD1 CNCWORD2 01/03 0,  ,   20
>   3) 2-Mar-16 CNC CNCWORD3 28/02, ,   1.60
>
> 4) 2-Mar-16    POS POSWORD3 POSWORD4 29/02 17,     ,102.3

And keywords database

> {CNC CNCWORD1, CNCWORD3, POS POSWORD1 CNCWORD2,  POS POSWORD3}

Using NLP from each line get the likely matching keyword

For above example, we shall have:

> 1) CNC CNCWORD1
>   2) POS POSWORD1 CNCWORD2
>   3) CNCWORD3
>   4) POS POSWORD3

Comment: in my opinion it is totally unnecessary to apply NLTK or other tools to solve this problem: if you have a list with categories what you want to find in your lines in your file, you only need to apply a find or match method in java.

Comment: Also notice that NLTK is Python, not Java.

Comment: @IstvanNagy thank you for your answer. Indeed I can only apply some find or match method in java for the most of case with regex expression to exclude some common word.